# How do you change brake lines on 2003 monte carlo ss

Tags: brake-lines

I want to change the rusty brake lines on my 2003 chevy monte carlo ss.  It looks almost impossible to get to the line clamps off.

Comment: You may have to cut the clamps and replace them along with the lines.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What's your question, exactly? Are you asking how to get clamps off, or something else? If you are looking at the end to end process you're unlikely to get great answers here, you're better off watching some tutorials which show how to use the tools and materials involved.